# PHP ECHO table with dynamic dropdown as one column using FOR EACH

Tags: php, html, for-loop, dropdown

I am a bit stuck I am attempting to build out a table with HTML and PHP. Ok got that done. Now I want to add a dynamic dropdown as one of the column options but cant seem to figure out how to mix the PHP, the HTML and the needed FOR EACH loop.

I know its currently wrong but am posting a variable of what I have been trying below.

```
    echo '<td>' . "<select>". "<option value =" . $sf_name . '&nbsp;'. $sl_name . ">" . $sf_name . '&nbsp;'. $sl_name . "</option>" .
    foreach($Staff_On_Duty as $person){         
  "<option value =" . $sf_name_option=$person->Staff_First_Name . '&nbsp;'. $sl_name_option=$person->Staff_Last_Name . ">" . $sf_name_option . '&nbsp;'. $sl_name_option . "</option>" 
    }
    . "</select>" .'</td>';
```

I need to have the currently selected individual at the top of the dropdown with the option to change that person out. the first .sf_name comes from higher in the code and gives me the name of the individual currently selected. The foreach runs from the $Staff_On_Duty query to give me everyone working right now. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it, essentially only fill the dropdown and mark the option that should have been selected (other stuff is a matter of preference):

```
echo("<td><select>");
foreach($Staff_On_Duty as $person){         
    $sf_name_option=$person->Staff_First_Name; // separated for clarity, you could also use $person->Staff_First_Name everywhere
    $sl_name_option=$person->Staff_Last_Name;
    echo("<option value = $sf_name_option&nbsp;$sl_name_option");
    if (($sf_name_option == $sf_name) && ($sl_name_option == $sl_name)) echo (" selected"); // this is the relevant part, but make sure variable values match!
    echo(">$sf_name_option&nbsp;$sl_name_option</option>"); 
}
echo("</select></td>");
```

Note that I did not put any quotation marks cause I have no idea what your variables entail, but it would need them if you don't have them in yet, i.e.:

```
... value=\"$sf_name_option&nbsp;$sl_name_option\" ...
```

Comment: Thanks much. That makes sense. I was too caught up on trying to get the Select as its own echo. That did the trick